# Determine parabola with given arc length between two known points

Tags: python, geometry, curve-fitting

Let (0,0) and (Xo,Yo) be two points on a Cartesian plane. We want to determine the parabolic curve, Y = AX^2 + BX + C, which passes from these two points and has a given arc length equal to S. Obviously, S > sqrt(Xo^2 + Yo^2). As the curve must pass from (0,0), it should be C=0. Hence, the curve equation reduces to: Y = AX^2 + BX. How can I determine {A,B} knowing {Xo,Yo,S}? There are two solutions, I want the one with A>0.

I have an analytical solution (complex) that gives S for a given set of {A,B,Xo,Yo}, though here the problem is inverted... I can proceed by solving numerically a complex system of equations... but perhaps there is a numerical routine out there that does exactly this?

Any useful Python library? Other ideas?

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque not necessarily. Any polynomial that passes through the origin has `x - 0` or simply `x` as a root. It thus cannot have a constant term independent of `x`.

Comment: By an arc length of `S`, I assume you mean that the length of the arc formed by `0, 0` and `x0, y0` is `S`?

Comment: This seems more like a math question than programming question to me.  Try work out the analytic solution on paper first?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Length_of_an_arc_of_a_parabola? In the nomenclature of that section you know *s* and *p* and want to compute *f*, as a first step. The equation there appears pretty transcendental to me, so I wouldn't hope for an exact formula. Different numeric approaches might be worth trying.

Comment: If you have `(A, B, x0, y0) -> S0` and it is not easy to invert, it is a simple 2D minimization problem where you want to minimize ´ abs( S - S0 )`, So you could try a simple least square algorithm....actually it is 1D as you have the restriction of the points it has to pass

Comment: An advanced "curve-fitting" library could do such a thing: find the curve from a family (say second order polynomials) that passes from two given points and has a given length. Of course it is mathematical, is not everything ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the arc length (line integral) of the quadratic `a*x0^2 + b*x0` is given by the integral of `sqrt(1 + (2ax + b)^2)` from `x = 0` to `x = x0`. On solving the integral, the value of the integral is obtained as `0.5 * (I(u) - I(l)) / a`, where `u = 2ax0 + b`; `l = b`; and `I(t) = 0.5 * (t * sqrt(1 + t^2) + log(t + sqrt(1 + t^2))`, the integral of `sqrt(1 + t^2)`.

Since `y0 = a * x0^2 + b * x0`, `b = y0/x0 - a*x0`. Substituting the value of `b` in `u` and `l`, `u = y0/x0 + a*x0`, `l = y0/x0 - a*x0`. Substituting `u` and `l` in the solution of the line integral (arc length), we get the arc length as a function of `a`:

```
s(a) = 0.5 * (I(y0/x0 + a*x0) - I(y0/x0 - a*x0)) / a
```

Now that we have the arc length as a function of `a`, we simply need to find the value of `a` for which `s(a) = S`. This is where my favorite root-finding algorithm, the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), comes into play yet again.

The working algorithm for the Newton-Raphson method of finding roots is as follows:

For a function `f(x)` whose root is to be obtained, if `x(i)` is the `i`th guess for the root,

```
x(i+1) = x(i) - f(x(i)) / f'(x(i))
```

Where `f'(x)` is the derivative of `f(x)`. This process is continued till the difference between two consecutive guesses is very small.

In our case, `f(a) = s(a) - S` and `f'(a) = s'(a)`. By simple application of the chain rule and the quotient rule,

```
s'(a) = 0.5 * (a*x0 * (I'(u) + I'(l)) + I(l) - I(u)) / (a^2)
```

Where `I'(t) = sqrt(1 + t^2)`.

The only problem that remains is calculating a good initial guess. Due to the nature of [the graph of `s(a)`](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/02pj5cjzhe), the function is an excellent candidate for the Newton-Raphson method, and an initial guess of `y0 / x0` converges to the solution in about 5-6 iterations for a tolerance/epsilon of `1e-10`.

Once the value of `a` is found, `b` is simply `y0/x0 - a*x0`.

Putting this into code:

```
def find_coeff(x0, y0, s0):
    def dI(t):
        return sqrt(1 + t*t)

    def I(t):
        rt = sqrt(1 + t*t)
        return 0.5 * (t * rt + log(t + rt))

    def s(a):
        u = y0/x0 + a*x0
        l = y0/x0 - a*x0
        return 0.5 * (I(u) - I(l)) / a

    def ds(a):
        u = y0/x0 + a*x0
        l = y0/x0 - a*x0
        return 0.5 * (a*x0 * (dI(u) + dI(l)) + I(l) - I(u)) / (a*a)

    N = 1000
    EPSILON = 1e-10
    guess = y0 / x0

    for i in range(N):
        dguess = (s(guess) - s0) / ds(guess)
        guess -= dguess
        if abs(dguess) <= EPSILON:
            print("Break:", abs((s(guess) - s0)))
            break
        print(i+1, ":", guess)

    a = guess
    b = y0/x0 - a*x0

    print(a, b, s(a))
```

[Run the example on CodeSkulptor](http://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user301_sZw8aDdZi1_0.py).

Note that due to the rational approximation of the arc lengths given as input to the function in the examples, the coefficients obtained may ever so slightly differ from the expected values.